# Why do these 2 elements not transition at the same time?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I have an element with 2 pseudo-elements (`.card-title::before` and `.card-title::after`) with a transition that changes the width from 0px to 40px.

The original transition speed is 0.5s, but for demonstration purposes I changed it to 15s so that you can clearly see that the `::before` pseudo-element starts before the `::after`.

*If you don't see it, try opening the Code Snippet in full page.*

**Why is this and how do I solve this?**

I can get around it by adding a very short (like 0.05s) delay to `::before`, but I think you can understand why I wouldn't like that idea.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: grid;
 place-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #eee;
}

.card {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

.card-body {
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
 background: #777;
}

.card-title {
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 height: 45px;
}

.card-title::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 width: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: width 15s linear;
}

.card-title::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 width: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: width 15s linear;
}

/* Hover effect */
.card-body:hover .card-title::before,
.card-body:hover .card-title::after {
 width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-body">
  <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply because one is called *before* and the other *after* :p

Comment: by the way on chrome both start at the same time for me .. it only happen on FF

Comment: In Chrome only inside the _Run code snippet_, but not when _Full page_ or _Copy snippet to answer_ & edit...

Comment: On Safari 11.0.1 both animations start simultaneously, both in Full Page and the small Snippet...

Comment: @Michał so the winner is Safari :p

Comment: Ahaha I guess :P But I just checked on Chrome Version 66.0 and they do start at different times... Though I have no clue why :D Regardless, this seems like a browser issue, so it may be hard to implement a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but your problem might be caused by a rounding issue, with one transition rounding down a pixel and one rounding up.

However, you can switch from using changing the widths to adjusting the scale, using `transform: scaleX(1);`, which is more performant anyway. The following works for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: grid;
 place-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #eee;
}

.card {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

.card-body {
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
 background: #777;
}

.card-title {
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 height: 45px;
}

.card-title::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 width: 40px;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: transform 15s linear;
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transform-origin: right;
}

.card-title::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 width: 40px;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: transform 15s linear;
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transform-origin: left;
}

/* Hover effect */
.card-body:hover .card-title::before,
.card-body:hover .card-title::after {
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-body">
  <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
 </div>
</div>
```